# Is the complex conjugate of the complex conjugate of f(x) = f(x)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Complex conjugate of $\overline f(x)$ ?= f(x)

I'm assuming it is:

f(x) = 1 + i

$\overline f(x)$ = 1 - i

second conjugate = 1 + i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't *assume* it is.  Use the definition to see that it is.  What does $f$ have to do with it?  If $z$ is a complex number, then $\overline{\overline{z}}=z$, and this is straightforward to show from the definition.

Comment: So my logic is wrong and the answer is no?

Comment: @macdonjo: How did you conclude this?  Suppose $z$ is a complex number.  The complex conjugate of that is denoted $\overline z$. So the complex conjugate of the complex conjugate is denoted $\overline{\overline z}$.  As I mentioned, and as you should show using the definition, for every complex number $z$, $z = \overline{\overline z}$.  That is true regardless of whether or not your $z$ is written as $f(x)$ for some mystery function $f$.

Comment: Me telling you "don't assume" is very different from telling you it isn't true. I mean, show it, don't assume it without reason.  I may have misunderstood your meaning of "assume," but either way I want to encourage you to show that it is true using the definition.